High Fidelity Playback requires connecting twice
The first time I connect a pair of Sony WH-1000XM3 to bluetooth (Ubuntu Noble, Intel AX201 Bluetooth device) it will always connect with low quality sound. I have to disconnect and reconnect to get the sound settings as High Fidelity Playback (A2DP sink, codec LDAC).
Why is this left to chance, or toggling? Surely there should be a setting to select one or the other?
Or is there at least a command I can run in the terminal to switch without having to disconnect and reconnect?
(FWIW I never have this issue connecting to my Android 14 phone)
